# Getting HTTP response from balanced

Tags: rest, balanced-payments

If I am using PHP code such as

```
$card = Balanced\Card::get("/v1/marketplaces/TEST-MP4K6K0PWGyPtXL4LZ42sQSb/cards/CC5N3HHUDrAyvhNwQOoUd3UX");
$card->unstore();
```

or

```
$customer->addCard($card)
```

how do I read the HTTP response from balanced to know if it has worked or what the error is?

Answer (score 3):

The Balanced client libraries are [written so that they will throw exceptions](https://github.com/balanced/balanced-php/blob/master/src/Balanced/Resource.php#L21) if there is a non 2xx HTTP response from the API.

The correct way to tell if the `addCard` operation failed for example would be to write some code that looks like

```
try {
    $customer->addCard($card)
} catch (Balanced\Error $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  So this will return and error message if there is a problem.  If there is not a problem, how would I read the 2xx HTTP response from the API.

Comment: It does not [look like the underlying library supports](https://github.com/matthewfl/restful/blob/master/src/RESTful/Resource.php) this functionality. I have [opened an issue](https://github.com/balanced/balanced-php/issues/85) to ask the author to look into this.